# OpenLayers 6 & RollupJS recipe

Tags: rollupjs, openlayers-6

I am trying to create a production build of OpenLayers 6 using RollupJS.
I want to produce a minimised ES6 module from which I can import classes in my code...I don't want to mix my code with the core OL classes. From what I've seen the default OpenLayers bundler, Parcel, & other options, cannot manage this.

All worked fine with OpenLayers-5 using ol-rollup (https://github.com/openlayers/ol-rollup).
However if I update to OpenLayers-6 & RollupJS <= 1.26.0
(https://github.com/flavour/ol-rollup), then I get the following error:

```
(!) `this` has been rewritten to `undefined`
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#error-this-is-undefined
node_modules\ol\layer\Tile.js
1: var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
                    ^
2:     var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
3:         extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
...and 1 other occurrence
node_modules\ol\source\XYZ.js
2:  * @module ol/source/XYZ
3:  */
4: var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
                    ^
5:     var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
6:         extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
...and 1 other occurrence
node_modules\ol\AssertionError.js
1: var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
                    ^
2:     var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
3:         extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
...and 1 other occurrence
...and 98 other files
```

The RollupJS website has these to say about this:
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-this-is-undefined
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#danger-zone

I have no idea how to use options.context or options.moduleContext to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the class inheritance code of the TypeScript compiler, which is used to transpile OpenLayers to ES5. One option is to configure rollup with

```
onwarn: function(warning, superOnWarn) {
  if (warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED') {
    return;
  }
  superOnWarn(warning);
}
```

The official OpenLayers+Rollup recipe (https://github.com/openlayers/ol-rollup) has been updated with this change recently.

Another option is to import the source modules instead of the transpiled ones in your application. So e.g. instead of

```
import Map from 'ol/Map'
```

you could

```
import Map from 'ol/src/Map'
```

For more information about this issue, you can refer to https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10245.